# Python 3, PyQt 5 - MP4 as resource file issue

Tags: python-3.x, video, pyqt5

I've made a desktop app using Python 3 and PyQt 5 and it works except for the playback of the MP4 video files (compiled by pyrcc5). They are visible and play on the video widget but there is a green line down the right side. I tried to put a green frame (using a Style Sheet) around the QVideoWidget but with no success.

Does anyone have any advice on how to resolve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: please share your code so that we can test on our systems

Comment: A search for `green line mp4` gets thousands of relevant hits. This problem is obviously not specific to qt - it can be caused by a whole host of different factors. You will need to provide much more information if you want help with this. To start with, provide a link to a video file that shows the problem, as well as a [mcve]. You should also state which platform you are on, and the specific graphics card and version of qt5 you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so I couldn't find anything on "MP4 and green line" so I looked at how to modify the PyQt5 interface as a way of hiding the issue.

The option I chose was QGroupBox and changing the padding in the stylesheet to -9 (in my particular case - you may find another value works better but it depends on the UI).

I did attempt to use QFrame, as my other option, but this didn't personally work for me.